# Using Regex to get cluster name from instance names prometheus relabel_configs

Tags: regex, prometheus

I have a bunch of autodiscovered ec2 instances that form a bunch of clusters.

For example I will have abc-def01.otherstuff, abc-def02.otherstuff and abc-def03.otherstuff, and I need to give them the label cluster which will be abc-def.

I've tried to add this to the prometheus config like so:

```
  - job_name: "ssl_mongo"
    ec2_sd_configs:
      - region: eu-central-1
        port: 27018
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: ['__meta_ec2_tag_Name']
        target_label: instance
        replacement: '$1:27018'
      - target_label: "role"
        replacement: "mongo_ssl_exporter"
      - source_labels: ['__meta_ec2_tag_Name']
        regex: '(\w+-[a-z]{3})'
        target_label: "cluster"
        replacement: '$1'
```

I've tested the regex using regexr and it seemed to work but when I look at prometheus, there's no cluster label at all.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to consider:

a) The Prometheus documentation says:

```
The regex is anchored on both ends. To un-anchor the regex, use .*<regex>.*
```

b) I think the "-" must be escaped

So, I would try the following regex:

```
(\w+\-[a-z]{3}).*
```

See the Prometheus documentation [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config)